# Is it possible to open a file that I uploaded from my local drive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have scenario where user can click on a link in a dialog box. While clicking on this link the link should be opened in a new window.

Here the links will be local files (like E:\docs\test.pdf) that user uploaded.

Here is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/inDiscover/Cuy8z/

## Code I used to open a file.

```
$(document).on("click", "#link_id", function (event) {
alert("clicked");
event.preventDefault();
window.open("E:/DOCUMENTS/test.txt");
});
```

Is this possible to do in any way. If possible please guide me to write a code for this. Or browser is blocking this as a security feature.

Comment: NO, Javascript has nothing to do with your user computer

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if a website could just randomly open files on your computer ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8758614/631619 for a valid approach